# Networkx MultiDiGraph inheritance: add_weighed_edges_from KeyError: None

Tags: python, networkx, keyerror

I tried to make PERT graph using MultiDiGraph. So, I tried to put a bool variable "_dirty" that checks whether the graph is deformed. However, the add_weighted_edges_from function does not work properly. Is the code wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```py
class ClassName(nx.MultiDiGraph):
    # some code..

    def add_edge(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """ add one edge """
        self._dirty = True
        super().add_edge(*args, **kwargs)
        
    def add_edges_from(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """ add several edges """
        self._dirty = True
        super().add_edges_from(*args, **kwargs)  

    def add_weighted_edges_from(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """ add several weighted edges """
        self._dirty = True
        super().add_weighted_edges_from(*args, **kwargs)
```

```
g = ClassName()
g.add_weighted_edges_from([(1,2,5),(2,3,10)])
```

error i got:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_15100/3885668308.py in <module>  
----> 1 g.add_weighted_edges_from([(1,2,5),(2,3,10)])    

~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_15100/2908507458.py in add_weighted_edges_from(self, *args, **kwargs)
     32         """  add several weighted edges """
     33         self._dirty = True
---> 34         super().add_weighted_edges_from(*args, **kwargs)
     35 
     36     def remove_node(self, *args, **kwargs):    

~\anaconda3\envs\pytorch_env\lib\site-packages\networkx\classes\graph.py in add_weighted_edges_from(self, ebunch_to_add, weight, **attr)  
    986         >>> G.add_weighted_edges_from([(0, 1, 3.0), (1, 2, 7.5)])
    987           
--> 988         self.add_edges_from(((u, v, {weight: d}) for u, v, d in ebunch_to_add), **attr)  
    989   
    990     def remove_edge(self, u, v):    

~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_15100/2908507458.py in add_edges_from(self, *args, **kwargs)  
     27         """ add several edges """  
     28         self._dirty = True  
---> 29         super().add_edges_from(*args, **kwargs)  
     30  
     31     def add_weighted_edges_from(self, *args, **kwargs):    

~\anaconda3\envs\pytorch_env\lib\site-packages\networkx\classes\multigraph.py in add_edges_from(self, ebunch_to_add, **attr)  
    571                 key = dd  # ne == 3 with 3rd value not dict, must be a key  
    572             key = self.add_edge(u, v, key)  
--> 573             self[u][v][key].update(ddd)  
    574             keylist.append(key)  
    575         return keylist    

~\anaconda3\envs\pytorch_env\lib\site-packages\networkx\classes\coreviews.py in __getitem__(self, key)  
     52  
     53     def __getitem__(self, key):  
---> 54         return self._atlas[key]  
     55  
     56     def copy(self):    

KeyError: None
```

Comment: Currently, the error is not reproducible. We don't know what the output of `main_route_list` is. Can you create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? `add_weighted_edges_from` in general works for MultiDiGraph. You also miss the `weight` parameter and the formatting is not ideal.

Comment: I edited! And i think it's because there is no key value. However, I wonder why the key value is not automatically generated despite the existence of  **kwargs .

Comment: I still cannot reproduce your error. Please add a full example, see for explanation the link above.

Comment: I changed example. hope it can be understand!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed that [`add_edge`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.MultiDiGraph.add_edge.html) returns the `key` in a `Multi(Di)Graph`. Adding the `return` resolves your issue:

```
class RailwayGraph(nx.MultiDiGraph):
    # some code..

    def add_edge(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """ add one edge """
        self._dirty = True
        return super().add_edge(*args, **kwargs)

    def add_edges_from(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """ add several edges """
        self._dirty = True
        super().add_edges_from(*args, **kwargs)

    def add_weighted_edges_from(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """ add several weighted edges """
        self._dirty = True
        super().add_weighted_edges_from(*args, **kwargs)


rg = RailwayGraph()
rg.add_weighted_edges_from([(1, 2, 5), (2, 3, 10)])
```

Comment: OMG thank you so much!! You're God